# React form input field wont let me change value

Tags: reactjs, forms, input

so I've seen this question asked before, but none of the previous answers have solved my issue. I can't figure out why my React won't let me change the value in the input box.

The state should be originally set by a value from my backend, but should then be altered when the user types a value in the input box.

- Thanks in advance!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class PRForm extends Component {

state = {
    pr: this.props.oneFish.pr
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.prBackend()
    this.prFrontend(event)
}

prFrontend = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    })
}


prBackend = () => {
    this.props.oneFish.pr = this.state.pr
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/fish/${this.props.oneFish.id}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.props.oneFish)
        }) 
        console.log(this.props.oneFish.pr)
}

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='prForm'>
                <div>
                    <h3 className='PR'>Biggest Catch: {this.state.pr} in. </h3>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="addPRForm">
                    <h4 className="pr-title">BIGGEST CATCH</h4>
                    <input className="inputPR" type="text" name='pr' placeholder="0 in" value={this.state.pr} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <input className="submitPR" type="submit" value="Submit Size" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PRForm
```

Comment: cant reproduce it. can you open a codesandbox project to show us the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for but I tried the same code on codesandbox and it worked fine.
Here is the link for it, check it out and lemmi know if I got your issue right. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dawn-bmmdb?file=/src/PRForm.js) Also I'd suggest you to use react-hook-form when you are working with form.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange.... Especially because this is an older project I'm looking back on, and I know it was working when I pushed it to github, but right now when I run my program I still can't even click in the text box.

Comment: Turns out my JS was fine, the issue was that on my CSS the form was positioned behind a div and I wasn't able to select the input box. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because react update asynchronously so the event might  be gone when react want to update the stateww to solve this just to store event in variable:

```
handleChange= (event) => {
const {name,value} = event.target
    this.setState({
        [name]:value
    })
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to change my ability to click in the text input box. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You defined you initial state as class property, so `this.state.pr` is always pointing to your initial state. Move it to the constructor instead:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      pr: this.props.oneFish.pr
   }
}
```

**Edit** this turns out to be not true. Still would recommend it as "good practice"